# Issue with DB Creation with Pyramid and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, creation

I'm building the Pyramid wiki from [this](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/tutorials/wiki2/) tutorial.

Everything works fine, except when try to create a folder for my models instead of having them in the file models.py in the main folder.

I created a models folder, added a `__init__.py` file to it, and a Page file with the content:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import Text

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Page(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a Page object. """
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
    data = Column(Text)

    def __init__(self, name, data):
       self.name = name
       self.data = data`
```

This doesn't work - I get a "can't find table named pages" error. This is my `models.py` file:

```
import transaction

from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import Text

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension 

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))

Base = declarative_base()

from test.models.Page import Page
```

Now if I replace the last line with this, everything works:

```
class Page(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a Page object. """
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
    data = Column(Text)

    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models.py file, you'll notice the `initialize_sql` function. This function calls the `Base.metadata.create_all()" function, which effectively creates all the tables for the objects that were defined using that Base object.

However, when you switched the `Page` class definition into the new file, you have created a new `Base` object. Since the `Page` class inherits from this new `Base` object, the `Base` object over in the models.py file never recognizes that the class definition even exists. Therefore, the `Base` object that is actually used to create the SQL tables appears to be empty, and therefore doesn't try to create the SQL table. This results in your "can't find table" error message.

To fix this, rather than creating a new `Base` object in your `models/__init__.py` file, have that file import `Base` from `mypackage/__init__.py`, and use that `Base` object as the superclass for `Page`.